# Using Blender Python API to create 2D animations neural nets

Tags: python, python-3.x, blender, blender-2.67

I want to use Blender and Python to create simplified 2D animations of theories on how the computation of the human brain create consciousness.  I have spent hours studying the Python-Blender API, and as of yet it is not clear how to do what I want to do.  Before I spend the much larger amount of time necessary to learn both Blender and its Python API, I would like to know if, and how, it is possible to use Blender-Python to:

1. Create thousands of lines under program control, in the form of long thin parallelograms, and place the two parallel narrow edges of each such line on selected locations on a selected pair of parallel lines in the image,
2. change the color and z-level of nets of connectioned lines formed
   out of such lines under python control, and
3. create, place, and change the coloring and z-level of some more
   complicated lines, such as ones having one or more bends in them.

I want to do these things to represent various synchronized activations of neural sub-networks.  I will be able to spend about a month or so learning and using the Blender and its Python API before the conference at which I want to display these animations, but before I start, I want to know if that is something that is realistically doable for a newbie in that time frame.

Thank you for any help you can give me. And if anybody would like to help me create such animations, I would happy to share the credit when they are placed on YouTube.  You can contact me at ewporter@gmail.com

Comment: Thanks you, Robert P., for putting my question in a better format.

Comment: [This playlist](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLMYtDzby1wdY3NMM07u9tV0eCJ1HM-llM) could be a good place to start